# dx.bat is not called in API version 23 while building in Android Studio / gradle

Tags: android, gradle, build, dex, dx

During build process of application, `dx.bat` in build `tools\23.0.3` folder is not executed.

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
```

`dx.bat` used to get executed in older API versions like 19.
In that case, can you let me know how classes.dex gets generated without dx.bat getting executed in API version 23.

Answer (score 1):

Version 2.1.0 of Android Gradle plugin includes a feature called [Dex In Process](https://medium.com/google-developers/faster-android-studio-builds-with-dex-in-process-5988ed8aa37e#.1cjsuxaqv), which allows to perform dexing in build process rather than in external processes.

From [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#revisions):

> The feature is enabled by default for projects that have set the
>   Gradle daemon's maximum heap size to at least 2048 MB. You can do this
>   by including the following in your project's gradle.properties file:
>
> ```
> org.gradle.jvmargs = -Xmx2048m
> ```
>
> To disable dexing-in-process, add the following code to your
>   module-level build.gradle file:
>
> ```
> android {
>   ...
>   dexOptions {
>       dexInProcess false
>   }
> }
> ```